# Creating a custom environment for reinforcement learning problems with delayed rewards and continuous time

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I want to create a custom environment for further RL tasks. There is one feature of the environment that I am not sure how to deal with. That is, the reward is not recorded right after the action, but after a period of "time".
(Since there is "time", there might need a "clock" so that the order of discrete events can be arranged?).

I looked for some tutorials somewhere and summarize as pseudo code as below. However, most of the open source code is for traditional RL environment, meaning that the reward is recorded right after the action. I am confused about what to do with the `def step(self, action):` function.

```
class env():

    def __init__(self):
        self.current_hour = 0
        
    #states
        self.observation = 0

    #actions
        self.actions = ['action1', 'action2']   #action space
        self.n_actions = len(self.actions)   #number of possible actions

    #rewards
        self.reward = 0    #reward
        self.done = False 

    def step(self, action):
        #1. Update the environment state based on the action chosen
        #2. Calculate the reward for the new state
        #3. Store the new observation for the state
        #4. Check if the episode is over and store as done
        return self.observation, self.reward, self.done
        
    def reset(self): #Reset the environment's state. Returns observation.
        self.done = False
        self.observation = 0        
        return self.observation
```